# Vector Helmholtz Equation

Tags: waves, vectors, coordinate-systems, differential-equations

In my recent exercise book I've derived the following equation that needs solving: $\nabla^2\vec{u} + k^2\vec{u} = 0.$ The deformation vectors points only in the $\hat{e}_r$ direction. I didn't want to write out the Laplace in spherical coordinates, so I tried using what I learned in my PDE course the previous semester. It turns out, the vector Helmholtz equation is quite different from scalar one we've studied.

Suppose I have basic knowledge in solving scalar Helmholtz in spherical (and other coordinate systems). Is there any analogy that translates over to the vector version? In other words, should I be able to solve vector Helmholtz if I can solve scalar versions?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed you can use your knowledge of the scalar Helmholtz equation. The difficulty with the vectorial Helmholtz equation is that the basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$ also vary from point to point in any other coordinate system other than the cartesian one, so when you act $\nabla^2$ on $\mathbf{u}$ the basis vectors also get differentiated. This forces you to calculate $\nabla^2 \mathbf{u}$ through the identity
$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{u} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} (\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{u}) - \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times (\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{u}) \tag{1}
$$
which is really cumbersome to deal with by brute force. A smart way to avoid all the hassle is by using the ansatz
$$
\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{r} \times (\boldsymbol{\nabla} \psi) \tag{2}
$$
where $\psi$ satisfies the *scalar* Helmholtz equation
$$
(\nabla^2 + k^2) \psi = 0.
$$

To check that $(\nabla^2 + k^2) \mathbf{u} = 0$ yourself you have to plug the ansatz $(2)$ on $(1)$ and make use of many vector identities and the scalar Helmholtz equation. The calculation is quite involved, so I'll point you to check Reitz, Milford & Christy's *Foundations of Electromagnetic Theory*, there they do the full calculation. With ansatz $(2)$ proven, it's just a matter of plugging the relevant mode $\psi_{lm}$ in eq. $(2)$ that you get your solution $\mathbf{u}_{lm}$.

Comment: Yes I figured the non-constant basis vectors are the source of problems (as I've seen in the solutions where we just wrote out the operator in spherical). This is just what I needed, thank you very much!